# C# path not being found

Tags: c#, filepath

I am currently trying to open a PDF file on page 16 using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`, but it won't pick up my file path. Here is my file path that I wish to open from `C:\Users\ipadc\Desktop\projek\Bookstore Bargainer System (4 Sept)\BookstoreBargainerSystem\bin\Debug\Pdfs\User_Manual`. Iit is stored in my Application.StartupPath. 
Here is the code i have tried but it says that it cannot find the path.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
   "Acrobat.exe /A \"page=16\" \""+Application.StartupPath+ "\\Pdfs\\User_Manual.pdf");
```

but it simply says `The file does not exist`.

Anybody knows why it cannot find this file. The file is an Adobe Acrobat type saved as `.pdf`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` and tell us the value of `StartInfo`.

Answer (score 4):

Your arguments cannot be part of the process.start.  This takes in the executable name.

The file name and arguments are different and need to be separated.

```
Process acro = new Process();
acro.StartInfo.FileName = "Acrobat.exe"
acro.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=16\" \""+Application.StartupPath+ "\Pdfs\User_Manual.pdf\""
acro.Start();
```

I also added an extra quote at the end of your path.

You can also do this instead, notice the arguments are a 2nd parameter of start here:

```
Process.Start("Acrobat.exe", "/A \"page=16\" \""+Application.StartupPath+ "\Pdfs\User_Manual.pdf\"");
```

And path the `Path.Combine` recommendation added (Marco's comment is right).

```
Process.Start("Acrobat.exe", 
    "/A \"page=16\" \"" +  
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Pdfs", "User_Manual.pdf") 
    + "\"");
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and I've just upvoted. But please don't merge paths using strings and slashes, use `Path.Combine` instead: `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Pdfs", "User_Manual.pdf")`. So you can avoid problems with slashes and special chars (I'm pretty sure your sample won't even compile or return a wrong path)

Comment: Thank you my first time using these so did not know that i had to allocate arguments seperatel. Thx for the help

Comment: @marco - you're right, I wouldn't have coded that way originally.  I added your recommendation.  Thanks.